# importing com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create GCM based application.
I followed the instructions as described in [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app).

In step number 4 I need to import the following line:

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
```

But I get an error:
[image]

As I said I followed all the steps, any idea why did it happend?

Comment: You jar file is not added to eclipse classpath

Comment: classpath means the package path or the project path?Because I added it to the project path

Comment: just add the relavent jar file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow below steps

1. create a lib folder under the project
2. put all jar files in lib folder
3. expand lib folder select all jars
4. right click  then buildpath and  select add to build path option

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project and Add to build path-

[image]

[image]